# How can I use an angular component more then once?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, charts, highcharts

I am using angular component to load dynamic charts into my widget:

Here is a example of my component:

```
angular.module("generalApp").component("chartPie", {
template: "<div class=Pie></div>",
bindings: {
    data: "=",
},
controller: function () {
    $('.Pie').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Pie point CSS'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            allowPointSelect: true,
            keys: ['name', 'y', 'selected', 'sliced'],
            data: [
                ['Apples', 29.9, false],
                ['Pears', 71.5, false],
                ['Oranges', 106.4, false],
                ['Plums', 129.2, false],
                ['Bananas', 144.0, false],
                ['Peaches', 176.0, false],
                ['Prunes', 135.6, true, true],
                ['Avocados', 148.5, false]
            ],
            showInLegend: true
        }]
    })
}
});
```

This renders a pie chart on the widget. This is how my json object looks likes:

```
{  
     "Id":0,
     "description":"Test1",
     "datasource":"Data",
     "charttype":"Pie",
     "x":0,
     "y":0,
     "width":3,
     "height":2
},
```

This is going good. But when I want to make another widget with a pie chart it doesn't render the pie chart anymore.

Array with two widgets objects:

```
[
    {  
        "Id":0,
        "description":"Test1",
        "datasource":"Data",
        "charttype":"Pie",
        "x":0,
        "y":0,
        "width":3,
        "height":2
    },
    {  
        "Id":0,
        "description":"Test2",
        "datasource":"Data",
        "charttype":"Pie",
        "x":3,
        "y":0,
        "width":3,
        "height":2
    }
]
```

On index.html

```
<div ng-switch-when="Pie">
   <chart-pie></chart-pie>
 </div>
```

The widgets:

[image: Render]

How can I use the component more then once?

Kind regards

Comment: it does not seem to be an issue with angular, check console if there any highchart errors

Comment: It seems they have the same ID. May be that's the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$('.Pie')` selector is too general and will pick up every element with that class in the whole document.

Inject `$element` into the controller and only search for `.Pie` within your component element:

```
angular.module("generalApp").component("chartPie", {
    template: "<div class=Pie></div>",
    bindings: {
        data: "=",
    },
    controller: function ($element) {
        $element.find('.Pie').highcharts({
            // ...
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir it fix my issue! Have a nice day.